# Телеграмм бот не видит любых слов

Tags: python, telebot

Я пишу на Python на библиотеке telebot.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from time import sleep
import functions 

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')
name = ""

#самое начало и то место, до куда бот почему то не доходит
@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def start(message):
    print("1") #это я удостоверился 
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ваше имя: ")
    
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def text(message):
    global name 
    print("2")#даже до сюда не доходит
    
    if name == "" and message.text != "/start":
        name = message.text
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id-1)
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{name}... Запомнила!")
        sleep(3)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id = msg.chat.id, message_id = msg.id, text = "Чтож, начнём!")
        sleep(2)
        bot.delete_message(msg.chat.id, msg.id)
        functions.slp(name, msg.chat.id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: А что вы пишете чтобы "зашло" в `def text(message):` ??

Comment: Уберите условие `and message.text != "/start"` оно в любом случае не будет таким

Answer (score 0):

Простой базовый пример отрабатывает типа этого ? [Клац Клац](https://habr.com/ru/post/580408/)

Вот ниже работающий пример реагирует на команду /start

У вас заработает этот код?

```
import telebot
token='наш токен'
bot=telebot.Telebot(token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Привет ✌️ ")
bot.infinity_poling()
```